# Tensorflow: How to switch channels of a tensor from RGB to BGR?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a quick way to convert tensors which encode an image from RGB to BGR?

In python that would be something like:

```
image = image[:, :, [2,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#strided_slice) or [`tf.reverse`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#reverse).

For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.reshape(tf.range(30), [2, 5, 3])

# the following two lines produce equivalent result:
img_channel_swap = img[..., ::-1]
img_channel_swap_1 = tf.reverse(img, axis=[-1])
```

Note that the api of `tf.reverse` is changed from tensorflow r1.0.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the channel is the last dimension.

```
channels = tf.unstack (image, axis=-1)
image    = tf.stack   ([channels[2], channels[1], channels[0]], axis=-1)
```

Comment: To me, this is the best answer as it is more general than the accepted answer (which only swaps axis from RGB to BGR or the opposite).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.split` as well.
Snippet from [tensorflow-vgg16/blob/master/vgg16.py#L5](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16/blob/master/vgg16.py#L5):

```
red, green, blue = tf.split(3, 3, rgb_scaled)
bgr = tf.concat(3, [blue, green, red])
```